# How to make sure nuget assemblies are added by package rather than only reference to DLL file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have noticed many times that developers tend to reference assemblies directly by browsing to the `.dll` file under the `.\packages` folder (installed by another project) and adding that to project references instead of installing the nuget package on that project. In that case, even though it compiles, but the Nuget Package Manager does not know that the referenced assembly is from a package, and so updating the package solution-wide does not update those references in that project. If you are doing a Service Oriented architecture where each piece of feature in your application is a separate project in the solution, then you probably have hundred of projects, and managing those references would become a nightmare. Is there any way to prevent developers from referencing assemblies directly if they belong to a nuget package? For example is there any MSBuild task to verify all references to package assemblies require the package to be installed on the project?

Comment: Do you have a Continuous Integration system? If so, a clean check out and build task on that ought to find such issues (eventually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your team uses resharper, they have a plugin to help with this:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/11/20/add-packages-not-references-a-nuget-plugin-for-resharper/

I'm guessing the issue is caused by people using resharper without it, since by default VS won't know to include that DLL but Resharper will find it and reference it (and not update package config without the plugin)

Also get used having people using nuget at the solution level, not project level. That will force people to update all nuget packages across the solution, and not leave you with V 1.1.1.0 on Project A and v 1.1.2.0 on Project B.

Comment: This helps and turns out it's bundled in ReSharper 8, however, it still does not prevent people from checking in an incorrectly referenced project.